# Invariants for the Weyl group of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n}$ acting on a certain group scheme

Tags: rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory, reflection-groups

Let $W$ denote the Weyl group of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n}$, so $W = (\mathbf{Z}/2)^{n-1} \rtimes \Sigma_n$. There is a natural action of $W$ on $\mathbf{Z}^n$ given by permutations and even numbers of sign changes. Let $G_1$ denote the group scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{Z}[b][x, \frac{1}{1+bx}])$ with addition $x + y + bxy$, and let $G_n = \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbf{Z}^n, G_1)$. The action of $W$ on $\mathbf{Z}^n$ defines an action of $W$ on $G_n$, where the analogue of a "sign change" is the map $x \mapsto -\frac{x}{1+bx}$.

What is an explicit description of the GIT quotient $G_n/\!\!/W$? (Feel free to invert $2$, if it simplifies things.)

If $b = 0$, this just becomes the standard GIT quotient of $\mathbf{A}^n$ by $W$, which is another copy of affine space; but if $b = 1$, this is the (complex) representation ring of $\mathrm{SO}_{2n}$, which is more complicated. It is not difficult to write down generators of the ring of functions on $G_n/\!\!/W$, but I'm having trouble writing down the relations between these generators.

Comment: Any chance that you'd be wiling to work with the representation ring of $\text{Spin}(2n)$ instead of $SO(2n)$? I believe that the rep ring of $\text{Spin}(2n)$ is a polynomial ring, generated by the characters of the fundamental representations, but the rep ring of $SO(2n)$ is messier.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yeah, I'm happy to do that, too, if that helps simplify my question!

Comment: Okay, I'll think about this and maybe post later tonight if someone else doesn't beat me too it.